# Scheduler, Vertical Resource View - same event multiple ressources

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I intend to buy/use Scheduler, for its [Vertical Resource View](https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar-scheduler/1.9.4/demos/vertical-resource-view.html), but I can't find out how or if this is possible: having an event that stretches across two or multiple ressources.
I know, that it's possible using multiple resources, as described [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-and-events).
The problem is that the event is drawn on each resource as a single event.
I want the event to be shown as one event, across all resources, something like in the image below.
Is this possible?

[It should look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PALQl.png)

Comment: I would guess it's not possible because there could be a case where the relevant resources are not drawn next to each other - e.g. the event is on resources A and C, but not on B

Comment: But maybe you can submit a feature request to ask that they are conjoined where the the resources are being displayed adjacent to each other.